# Microsoft Graph OneDrive invite fails when inviting group alias

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We are seeing what appears to be a change in the behavior of the Graph API. Our code, which grants access for an Excel workbook in OneDrive to a specific Security Group, is now failing where it used to succeed.

Request:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/groups/d4826b5d-4106-40a6-97e0-3826dff58e17/drive/root:/sageData/_verbs.xlsx:/invite HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <<token omitted>>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 127
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{
    "recipients": [{
        "alias": "d536e908-60cb-4558-8b3a-38f033d6508a"
    }],
    "requireSignIn": true,
    "sendInvitation": false,
    "roles": ["Write"]
}
```

Response:

```http
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 48f148b6-0c15-410e-b29d-bef5880c7007
client-request-id: 48f148b6-0c15-410e-b29d-bef5880c7007
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceB","Ring":"NA","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_14","ADSiteName":"DUB"}}
Duration: 981.5167
Date: Wed, 15 Nov 2017 13:05:50 GMT
Content-Length: 247

{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "One of the provided recipients could not be found",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "48f148b6-0c15-410e-b29d-bef5880c7007",
            "date": "2017-11-15T13:05:51"
        }
    }
}
```

However, we can see that "recipient"" (which is the Security Group id) does indeed exist:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/d536e908-60cb-4558-8b3a-38f033d6508a
```

Response

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
    "id": "d536e908-60cb-4558-8b3a-38f033d6508a",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "classification": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2017-11-15T12:42:01Z",
    "description": "{\"datasetIdentifier\":\"4122e61b-d5c1-4a58-9068-dfdeda9e8278\",\"roleIdentifier\":\"FullAccess\",\"isSageMetadata\":true,\"type\":\"Role\"}",
    "displayName": "Sage - Pete - All Apps & Add-Ins",
    "groupTypes": [],
    "mail": null,
    "mailEnabled": false,
    "mailNickname": "Sage-Pete-AllApps-Add-Ins",
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
    "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
    "proxyAddresses": [],
    "renewedDateTime": "2017-11-15T12:42:01Z",
    "securityEnabled": true,
    "visibility": null
}
```

The documentation states the recipient property we are posting should be "email" whereas we have used "alias" up to this point. If we change to "email" then it works.

However, that seems incorrect, according to [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driverecipient) we should use `alias`:

> "The alias of the domain object, for cases where an email address is unavailable (e.g. security groups)."

Has anyone else encountered this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

What you're submitting as an `alias` is actually an `objectId`. The `alias` in this case would be the object's `mailNickname` (i.e. `Sage-Pete-AllApps-Add-Ins`).

Either of these should work:

```json
{
    "recipients": [{
        "objectId": "d536e908-60cb-4558-8b3a-38f033d6508a"
    }],
    "requireSignIn": true,
    "sendInvitation": false,
    "roles": ["Write"]
}
```

or

```json
{
    "recipients": [{
        "alias": "Sage-Pete-AllApps-Add-Ins"
    }],
    "requireSignIn": true,
    "sendInvitation": false,
    "roles": ["Write"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. That makes sense. However our code using the `alias` with group `id` has been working since February 2017, and has only broken in the last few days - this appears to be a change in behaviour of the Graph API

Comment: And, as I said above, using `email` with the group `id` guid worked for me - and this isn't an email address any more than an alias!

Comment: Marc, we tried using "objectId" but that fails, the same as "alias". "email" appears to be the only working property now, even though I'm using a guid as the value.

Comment: I would think the `id` as `alias` change may just be a bug fix (I wouldn't have expected that to work). As for why `email` is working with `id`, that sounds like a bug as well. I'll see if I can sort out why `objectId` isn't working with `id`. It may be that this should be a reference rather than a string (need to test later today).